# Prevent Suggestion for Input Field in HTML in All browser

Tags: html

I have an HTML form Which Contains the Various Field.

Simply We all Know that every browser will show some suggestion for the input field.

Like an Email Input field. When you enter or click on that input it shows the previously entered email or any other values.
I have cleared and done all procedures for stopping that behavior.  But still, I get previously entered data in the input field. (as in shown in image)

So how do I remove that suggestion or previously entered data? 
Or How do I prevent that automatic suggestion for the input field?

This is my HTML Sample Code for Input Field.

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" id="login_email" required placeholder="User Email" data-parsley-type="email">
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Yes it may Duplicate But I did not get it at first. So i asked it here. @AbdulJabbarWebBestow & thanks for the answer sir.

Comment: You are always welcome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

Comment: Sir you already notify me in first comment why you keep suggesting it? @AbdulJabbarWebBestow

Comment: Sorry about that but SO always prefer to answer/comment in moderate way and that's I had to show it again as per SO's flagging option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_autocomplete.asp)

I have added the

> autocomplete="off"

In  Your code. Try it.

```
<div class="form-group ">
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" id="login_email" required placeholder="User Email" data-parsley-type="email" autocomplete="off">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks It's working. Can You Please Tell me is this competabel with all browser ?

Comment: Please See my suggested Link For More Info. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can set

```
<input type="text" name="email" autocomplete="off" />
```

And some browsers like Firefox 3.0.X may still show cached objects so you can set your `<form>` tag with `autocomplete="off"`.

For more detailed answers, please visit

[How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)